# Incorrect ORDER BY PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I'm having a weird problem when I'm trying to order my column. The column is different than usual tables I'm working with where the43 is usually a comma in the numbers. Here the numbers have no comma and when I order the column I get something like

| company_id |
| --- |
| 10097 |
| 1024 |
| 10304 |
| 151 |

Any help? Ideally I'd like to turn these numbers into numbers with commas so it's consistent with other tables when I do joins later

Comment: Column data type? Integer would help, but I'd guess it's varchar here...

Comment: Never store numbers in `text` columns - you just found out one reason why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Numbers and comma's in a single field, stored as text. Sounds like a major problem, and ordering is just one of them. Please fix your datamodel asap, it will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the values are strings.  You can sort them in one of two ways.  The first is the "string" way:

```
 order by length(company_id), company_id
```

The second is to convert to a number:

```
order by company_id::numeric
```